# Struct Mapping: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not unique for

Tags: truffle-contract, truffle-compile, openzeppelin-contracts

Using openzepplin version 2.0.0 and solc version 0.5. I am writing an ERC721 token contract on truffle. Truffle compiles with no error on solc 0.4.23. I had to upgrade to 0.5 due to openzepplin version.

Here's declaration for mapping:

```
struct Coordinates {
        string ra;
        string dec;
        string mag;
    }

    struct Star { 
        string name;
        string story;
        Coordinates coordinates;
    }

mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo;
```

Here's the method for returning Star mapping:

```
function tokenIdToStarInfo(tokenId) public view returns(string, string, string, string, string) {
        return (tokenIdToStarInfo[tokenId].name, 
        tokenIdToStarInfo[tokenId].story, 
        tokenIdToStarInfo[tokenId].coordinates.ra, 
        tokenIdToStarInfo[tokenId].coordinates.dec, 
        tokenIdToStarInfo[tokenId].coordinates.mag);
    }
```

Here's console for the truffle compilation error:

> starNotary.sol:21:5: The previous declaration is here:
>       mapping(uint256 => Star) public tokenIdToStarInfo;
>       ^-----------------------------------------------^
>
> starNotary.sol:80:32: DeclarationError: Identifier not found or not
>   unique.
>       function tokenIdToStarInfo(tokenId) public view returns(string, string, string, string, string) {
>                                  ^-----^

Comment: Open Zeppelin 2.0.0 relies on Solc 0.4.24. So `I had to upgrade to 0.5 due to openzepplin version` doesn't quite add up here.

Comment: I guess the Open Zeppelin version was 2.1. Anyways I have downgraded to Solc 0.4.24 and the issue is resolved.